# Applying ServiceContract and OperationContract on existing interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have some existing interfaces that are used over all over system.

Now I want to use one of the interfaces to be as service contract.

But the problem is that I need to add `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` attributes on existing interfaces and they will contaminate the rest of the code .

Any solution to this problem with out duplicating the interfaces?

Applying the attributes on the concrete implementation ? is that a good practice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply extend the interface with a service-warpper type interface, i.e.:

```
public interface IMyCode
{
    string GetResult();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyCodeService : IMyCode
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetResult();
}
```

C# allows interface inheritance, and the compiler will spit out a warning that `IMyCodeService.GetResult` requires new because it hides the `IMyCode.GetResult` method, but not appending `new` will not break the implementation, as an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyCodeService service = new MyCodeService();
        IMyCodeService serviceContract = (IMyCodeService)service;
        IMyCode codeContract = (IMyCode)service;

        service.GetResult();
        serviceContract.GetResult();
        codeContract.GetResult();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IMyCode
{
    void GetResult();
}

public interface IMyCodeService : IMyCode
{
    void GetResult();
}

public class MyCodeService : IMyCodeService
{
    public void GetResult()
    {
        Console.Write("I am here");
    }
}
```

That way, you can provide a service contract based on your existing interface without changing your existing code.

If you share your contract assembly instead of using WCF to generate a proxy for you, you can even pass your service contract in places where you'd accept your existing interface, because the service interface inherits from it.

Comment: Shouldn't You add a `new` keyword to inherited interface to each `[OperationContract]`?

Answer (score 0):

we are slowly trying to move to WCF and got the same problem. We couldnt figure out another way apart from decorating Service interface with attributes. They are attributes so hopefully shouldnt pollute the code that much.

One thing we had to do (when moving form legacy Web Services, is to make sure all dependencies are moved to common place so that they can be called both from Global.aspx and WCF Host Service)

You have to implement attributes on the concrete implementation (mainly ServiceBehavior related attributes) so that WCF Host can host it. As to OperationContract, we mainly applied to interfaces.